# Alterar valor padrão de uma parâmetro de uma função

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou migrando um sistema feito em Codeigniter da versão 2 para a 3, já fiz a grande parte dos [passos que o manual](https://cibr.github.io/User-Guide-CodeIgniter-PtBr/installation/upgrade_300.html) diz mas tem um deles que estou com uma dúvida, o [passo 11](https://cibr.github.io/User-Guide-CodeIgniter-PtBr/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-11-usage-of-xss-filtering), pois diz que algumas funções que faziam o filtro de xss agora mudaram o padrão, agora tendo que passar um segundo valor como TRUE quando quiser que aquele post, por exemplo, seja filtrado.

Mas enfim, já estou fazendo da seguinte forma, criei um arquivo MY_Input que extende de Input e reescrevi essas funções, como get, post e get_post, só que não sei a forma mais correta de fazer essa reescrita, se assim:

```
public function get($index = NULL, $xss_clean = TRUE)
{
    return parent::get($index, $xss_clean);
}
```

ou assim:

```
public function get($index = NULL, $xss_clean = TRUE)
{
    return $this->_fetch_from_array($_GET, $index, $xss_clean);
}
```

ou se tem alguma outra forma mais correta em se fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter depreciou o uso do filtro xss massivo e de forma automática. Para fazer isso você deve filtrar cada input separadamente, dessa forma:

```
 $this->input->post('meuInput',TRUE)
```

Comment: Sim, e com isso minha dúvida, para não ter que alterar cada input eu sei que posso criar um arquivo em application/core extendendo o core/input e reescrever ou acrescentar os métodos de lá. Dai qual a forma mais correta de se fazer isso?